# How to get rid of wixca.dll and print Eula in WIX v3

Tags: wix

I am a complete newbie in WIX and currently I am working on upgrading a WIX project from version 2 to version 3. The following fragment prints Eula with wixca.dll that is copied from WIX version 2 (as far as I can guess):

```
<Fragment>
<!-- print EULA functionality -->
    <CustomAction Id="WixUIPrintEula"
              BinaryKey="WixUIWixca"
              DllEntry="PrintEula"
              Return="ignore"
              Execute="immediate" />
    <Binary Id="WixUIWixca"
        SourceFile="wixca.dll" />
</Fragment>
```

How to get rid of this wixca.dll and what is the right way to print Eula in WIX 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wix v3 does not contain a `wixca.dll`, you print an EULA nativly through the UI with v3. Pick one of the shipped UI sets that support an EULA and specify it as follows:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="bobpl.rtf" />
```

See [Customizing Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) for some examples.