# The system cannot find the file "wixca.dll"

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.7, wix3.6, wix3.8

[image]I migrated the project from Wix 2.0 to 4.0, then when i am trying to build the project from visual studio 2017 (Votive) to generate installer software package, I am getting the below error:

The system cannot find the file "wixca.dll"

I looked into the below path and didn't find the dll:

ProgramFiles\Wix Toolset v4.0\bin

In my **LicenseAgreementDlg.wxs** file, i am using the below code and from here using Value="WixUIPrintEula" we are calling **Common.wxs** file

```
<Control Id="LicenseText" Type="ScrollableText" X="20" Y="60" Width="330" Height="140" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no">
                    <Text SourceFile="$(var.LicenseFile)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Print" Type="PushButton" X="76" Y="243" Width="65" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIPrint)">
                    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIPrintEula">1</Publish>
                </Control>
```

I am using "wixca.dll" in my Common.wxs file

like as shown below:

```
<Fragment>
<CustomAction Id="WixUIPrintEula" BinaryKey="WixUIWixca" DllEntry="PrintEula" Return="ignore" Execute="immediate"/>
<Binary Id="WixUIWixca" SourceFile="wixca.dll"/>
</Fragment>
```

Please help me where can i get wixca.dll?

Comment: Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have a Custom Actions to perform along with the installer. Check for any other projects that creates the wixCA.dll.

Answer (score 0):

***Eliminate Fragment***: As I wrote in [a previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274061/error-lght0094-the-identifier-customactionwixuiprinteula-could-not-be-found#comment91626715_52274061), maybe read this answer: **[How to get rid of wixca.dll and print Eula in WIX v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009254/how-to-get-rid-of-wixca-dll-and-print-eula-in-wix-v3)**. In summary it looks like this snippet for license agreement printing is no longer necessary in WiX 3 and upwards provided you [use a standard WiX dialog set](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html). Just try to take out the whole fragment and set a WiX dialog set and see if this solves the problem.

***WiX Dialog Set***: To add a standard dialog set in WiX Votive (Visual Studio).

- In Visual Studio, for your WiX project: add a project reference to `%ProgramFiles (x86)%\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUIExtension.dll`.
- Set the Mondo default GUI in your WiX source: **`<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />`** (comment out other UIRef elements). Or set another set, [list here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html).
- Test compile. Your setup should now magically have a default set of standard dialogs.

---

***WixCA.dll***: For the record **`WixCA.dll`** contains [WiX standardized custom actions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/) (funny concept: standard custom actions - linguistic flower) and this DLL is compiled into the Binary table of any WiX-built MSI which uses the built-in custom actions provided with WiX.

A WiX source that uses these custom actions will have the namespace  `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"` added to its top WiX element. There could be other cases when it is also compiled into the Binary table, but certainly if that namespace is there - and any custom action elements are added. Look for elements starting with `<util:.....>`  (there are many custom actions in addition to that namespace. [See documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/).

Comment: I don't remember WiX 2 that well, so I am sort of on shaky ground. However, the GUI related wxs files you refer to: `LicenseAgreementDlg.wxs` and similar **might** be unnecessary, unless they are actively customized with unique features for your project. If they are, then you have complex migration to do, but if the dialogs are just normal run-of-the-mill dialogs without any complexity, then you can replace them with the default dialog sets obtained from WixUIExtension.dll. when you run through the WiX2 dialogs, do you see any custom fields? Any non-standard values?

Comment: Maybe you can add a screenshot to the question so we can see if it is standard or not. Probably not.

Comment: Hmm, I have no access to WiX2, but that looks custom made for sure. Do you have access to the old WiX2 installer MSI? Or do you just have sources? If you have the original installer MSI files, maybe try to decompile them with the WiX 4 decompiler `dark.exe`. It is extremely important that you use version 4. If that works, the decompiled wxs should be useful as WiX 4 dialogs. Maybe.